# Match with specific content within html tags using Regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to match 'script' tags if it contains `'bb'` inside, it could be anything between `'bb'` and the `'script'` tag including line break, so I use `[\s\S]*`?

Here is the text I'm working with:

```
<script>
 aa
</script>
<script>
 bb
</script>
<script>
 cc
</script>
```

Pattern is: `<script>[\s\S]*?bb[\s\S]*?<\/script>`

But this also matches `'script'` tag with `'aa'` inside, I tried many times but not working, then how to match script tags with only `'bb'` inside?

Comment: pattern: `/<\s*script[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*script>/gi` then check the contents

Comment: [Tony the pony he comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Seblor True that, although regex can still be used on simple text like the one OP provided

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing HTML using regex isn't a good idea as it may give you unexpected results when your script tags are nested.

But just in case your tags aren't nested, you can use this regex, which will match only script tag that contains `bb` inside it and will not span over multiple script tags as it is happening right now. In your regex `[\s\S]*?` matches any character due to which it also matches sequential `<script>` tags starting from first `<script>` tag spanning more than just one `<script>` tag to cover `bb`.

```
<script>(?:(?!<script>)[\s\S])*?bb(?:(?!<script>)[\s\S])*?<\/script>
```

This regex is almost same as your regex and the only different I have done is, I have changed `[\s\S]*?` part to `(?:(?!<script>)[\s\S])*?` this regex which doesn't allow capturing multiple `<script>` tags in a single match and hence matches only one script tag at a time.

Let me know if this works for you.

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AsnhST/1)**

Comment: It works! This is using look ahead which I will need to try, this is working now!

Comment: @Dew: Good to know it worked well for you. Also please consider accepting the answer which will give you +2 rep and might be helpful for others in following an answer to a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<script>\s+bb\s+<\/script>`

Explanation:

`<script>` - match `<script>` literally

\s+bb\s+`- match one or more white spaces with`\s+`, match`bb`literally, again  match one or more white spaces with`\s+`

`<\/script>` - match `</script>` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8VxLhl/1)

You use `[\s\S]`, which matches **every** character: `\s` - matches any white space, `\S` - matches everything except whitespace. This is the reason why your pattern didn't work.

Comment: My pattern works half right, it matches from the first 'script' tag which is wrong, but ends with the right script tag, I want to match starts from the second 'script' tag. I use \s\S because it could be more than one characters(including space)